# Threads not waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please see the code below. I not not getting the "Count" in main as "5" always. could someone help Please.

```
    class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() => new Test("a"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() => new Test("b"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(() => new Test("c"));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(() => new Test("d"));
        Thread t5 = new Thread(() => new Test("e"));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();
        t4.Start();
        t5.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
        t3.Join();
        t4.Join();
        t5.Join();

        Console.WriteLine(Test.Names.Count);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static ListClass<string> Names { get; set; }

    public Test(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        //Thread.Sleep(10);
        if (Names == null)
            Names = new ListClass<string>();
        Names.Add(name);
    }
}

public class ListClass<T>
{
    private List<T> mylist = new List<T>();
    private object myLock = new object();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (myLock)
        {
            mylist.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return mylist.Count; }
        private set
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a chance of a race condition, which means that between the time a thread has check if Names is null another has already initialised it, thus overwriting it, reducing the count as its a new collection, put a lock around the null check, not the best solution but will work.

Comment: How to handle it ? I have added lock :( ...Place object mylist = new List<T>(); ?

Comment: The simplest way is to make a static constructor on Test to initialize "Names", or a private variable with an initializer that the Names property accesses.

Comment: Thanks, Will try that.

Comment: Yes a static ctor will also do the trick, they are thread safe.

Comment: Yes worked with static constructor. Thanks a lot... add it as an answer..I will mark. it...Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help added ans

Comment: This looks like it's probably either homework or you just experimenting with concurrency in .Net, but in case it isn't, the BCL has provided thread-safe collections since .Net 4 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx), and you'd be better off using `ConcurrentBag<T>` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) here rather than rolling your own version of a thread safe list.

Comment: @Relativity your `Count` implementation may lead to other issues in multithreaded environment in other cases. You need to lock on it too. There is a build in version of a synchronized list in .Net Framework: [SynchronizedCollection(of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance of a race condition, which means that between the time a thread has check if Names is null another has already initialised it, thus overwriting it, reducing the count as its a new collection.

Put a lock around the null check, or use a static constructor in test class to initialise the collection, not the best solution but will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Names == null) 
{
    lock(_sync)
    {
        if (Names == null)
        {
            Names = new ListClass<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Use [double-locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) technique to avoid race condition.
Or class `Lazy<T>`, which is rather usefull for such scenarios.